# Import extensions of Array interface/prototype in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have created a ts file array.extensions.d.ts for extending arrays in my node project.

```
export {};

declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    remove(o: T): Array<T>;
    isEmpty: boolean;
    isNotEmpty: boolean;
    first: T;
    last: T;
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'isEmpty', {
  configurable: true,
  get() {
    return this.length === 0;
  },
});

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'isNotEmpty', {
  configurable: true,
  get() {
    return this.length > 0;
  },
});

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'first', {
  configurable: true,
  get() {
    return this[0];
  },
});

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'last', {
  configurable: true,
  get() {
    return this[this.length - 1];
  },
});

Array.prototype.remove = function (o) {
  const i = this.indexOf(o);
  if (i > -1) {
    return this.splice(i, 1);
  }
  return [];
};
```

I also added "./src/shared/extensions" to the typeRoots property in my tsconfig.json file.

In VScode IntelliSense i see the new properties of the arrays and i can use them without any errors showing up.

I use it, for example, like this:

```
console.log('isEmpty', ['x', 'y', 'z'].isEmpty);
```

But when running my code i get the error message
`Property 'isEmpty' does not exist on type 'string[]'`

I am not sure, if and where i need to import my extension file. In the IDE everything seems fine without any import at all.

So if someone could point me in the right direction, this would be awesome.

Thank you

Comment: What is `User`? That's not shared in the question

Comment: `.d.ts` files are used for declarations(typings for IntelliSense), they don't offer any funcionality, you probably need a `ts` file instead (renaming `d.ts` to `ts` should fix the problem)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I changed my initial question and remove the User-array to a simple array of strings. Same error

Comment: @nickzoum I changed the filename to array.ts, but nothing has changed

Comment: Did you actually import the file?

Comment: @Skee Are you importing the file anywhere in the project? sounds like using `import './src/shared/extensions';` in your main/index file should fix the problem.

Comment: @Skee It can always be a bit tricky when dealing with global updates, I find it best to avoid declaring global extensions and rather import the functions when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I manually added

```
import '../../shared/extensions/array';
```

to my index file and now it works.